# Lining up sub and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I'm trying to typeset some (extended) [Sweedler notation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Sweedler+notation) (if you want context); something like

```
$ {{b_{(1)}}^{(1)}}_{(1)} $
```

This trick of enclosing things in more and more curly brackets seems to work fine for one subscript and one superscript, but in this example with three indices, we get:

[image: Example]

Notice that the 3rd index is lower than the 1st.

> What would be a better way to typeset this?

Comment: your third subscript is subscripting `b_{(1)}` so has to be lower, you could simply use `b {}_{(1)} {}^{(1)} {}_{(1)}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
$ {{b_{(1)}}^{(1)}}{}_{(1)} $
```

In your code, the second subscript is appended to the entire preceding formula, hence it is placed lower than anything in that formula.  So, I just appended that second subscript to empty brackets instead, and it seems to deliver:

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course!  Thankyou.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `tensor` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tensor}

\begin{document}

\[
\tensor{b}{^{(1)}_{(1)}^{(1)}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]